# single-dimension cell array conversion to two-dimension cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell array of size 1*15. Each cell array has different matrix sizes and has been generated from a big matrix. I know cell arrays have to be reshaped to 3*5 to produce the large matrix. I want to be able to reshape the 1*5 cell array it to a matrix of size 3*5 and then produce a single large matrix whose elements come from cell matrix of 3*5 size.

Further detail: My original matrix has 14451*24557 size. I truncated it into smaller blocks of 6000*6000 using "mat2tiles" command. Then, I produced a cell array of 1*15 out of it to conduct certain operations using "parfor". Now, I want to reshape back into the original matrix size. Any idea?

Comment: We're grasping at straws here. Please add the sizes/contents of your matrices (input) with the desired large matrix (output). You desire a function similar to `reshape` but for cells, right?

Comment: @Adriaan, `reshape` works for cells. Doesn't it? `size(reshape({1,3,4,5},2,[]))` produces `[2 2]`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I just found out, see my answer. The documentation just does not mention it as a valid input, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what do you know. [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) actually works with cells. Weird that the documentation does not say that, but it works like this:

```
a=cell(15,1);
reshape(a,5,3)
ans = 
    []    []    []
    []    []    []
    []    []    []
    []    []    []
    []    []    []
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it this what you are searching for?

```
a(1).test = zeros(1,15)
reshape(a(1).test,3,5)
```

thats for one...
for more simply:

```
  a(2).test = zeros(1,15)
  [reshape(a(1).test,3,5) reshape(a(2).test,3,5)]
```

related to the comments by Adriaan...
The above is for structs for cell arrays its comparable

```
a=1:15;
b=16:30;
a =num2cell(a);
b =num2cell(b);
reshape([a b],5,6)
```

Comment: Note that you have used a structure here, which is not what the OP is after.

Comment: It isn't clear to me. Could you please add more detail please. Let's say, if I have a cell array "pts" with 1*5 size. How can I reshape it to 3*5?

Comment: You cannot put 5 arguments into 15 assigned locations, that'll get you a dimension error.

Comment: Then you should change your answer accordingly, because as it stands it is "not useful" since the OP does not have a structure.

Comment: yes Andras, I didn't notice that reshape is working for cell variables as well. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: ok here the corrected version     `a=1:15;
b=16:30;
a =num2cell(a);
b =num2cell(b);
reshape([a b],5,6); `